# Java's jar: How do I create a .jar file from a specific list of files and also use the -C option?

Tags: java, jar

The jar, like POSIX tar, supports a -C option which allows the user to change directory before including some files

```
$> man jar
[... snip ...]
-C dir
    When creating (c) or updating (u) a JAR file, this option temporarily changes the directory while processing files specified
    by the file operands. Its operation is intended to be similar to the -C option of the UNIX tar utility. For example, the
    following command changes to the classes directory and adds the Bar.class file from that directory to my.jar:

    jar uf my.jar -C classes Bar.class
[... snip ...]
```

However I'm having difficult trying to combine this -C feature with the @arg-file feature:

```
$> man jar
<... snip ...>
jar c[efmMnv0] [entrypoint] [jarfile] [manifest] [-C dir] file ... [-Joption ...] [@arg-file ...]
[... snip ...]
@arg-file
    To shorten or simplify the jar command, you can specify arguments in a separate text file and pass it to the jar command
    with the at sign (@) as a prefix. When the jar command encounters an argument beginning with the at sign, it expands the
    contents of that file into the argument list.
[... snip ...]
```

In this example I have this tree:

```
$> find .
.
./out
./src
./src/com
./src/com/dot
./src/com/dot/something
./src/com/dot/something/etc
./src/com/dot/something/etc/Two.class
./src/com/dot/something/etc/Three.class
./src/com/dot/something/etc/One.class
./src/com/dot/something/etc/Four.class
./list.txt
```

The idea is to pack the jar so that it contains the contents as so:

```
$> jar tvf out/myjar.jar
     0 Fri Jan 03 16:17:44 GMT 2020 META-INF/
    69 Fri Jan 03 16:17:44 GMT 2020 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Fri Jan 03 16:11:16 GMT 2020 com/dot/something/etc/One.class
     0 Fri Jan 03 16:11:20 GMT 2020 com/dot/something/etc/Two.class
     0 Fri Jan 03 16:11:24 GMT 2020 com/dot/something/etc/Three.class
     0 Fri Jan 03 16:11:26 GMT 2020 com/dot/something/etc/Four.class
```

i.e. it removes the "src/"

I have tried the obvious:

```
$> jar cvf out/myjar.jar   -C src/     com/dot/something/etc/One.class com/dot/something/etc/Two.class
com/dot/something/etc/Two.class : no such file or directory
added manifest
adding: com/dot/something/etc/One.class(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
```

but that fails as it can find some files, but not others, which is strange!

I have tried by using this list as the arg-file:

```
$> cat list.txt
com/dot/something/etc/One.class
com/dot/something/etc/Two.class
com/dot/something/etc/Three.class
com/dot/something/etc/Four.class

$> jar cvf out/myjar.jar   -C src/   @list.txt
com/dot/something/etc/Two.class : no such file or directory
com/dot/something/etc/Three.class : no such file or directory
com/dot/something/etc/Four.class : no such file or directory
added manifest
adding: com/dot/something/etc/One.class(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
```

But that fails in the same way.

I have also tried to prefix the `src/` directory onto the name, but it fails by finding some files and not others -- but this time in the opposite way!

```
$> jar cvf out/myjar.jar   -C src/    src/com/dot/something/etc/One.class src/com/dot/something/etc/Two.class
src/src/com/dot/something/etc/One.class : no such file or directory
added manifest
adding: com/dot/something/etc/Two.class(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
```

**Q: How do you make the `jar` tool work with both a list of specific files and the `-C` option?**

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT the only way to get this to work is some insane hybrid of both types of path, i.e.:

```
$> jar cvf out/myjar.jar   -C src/   com/dot/something/etc/One.class src/com/dot/something/etc/Two.class
added manifest
adding: com/dot/something/etc/One.class(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: com/dot/something/etc/Two.class(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
$> jar tvf out/myjar.jar
     0 Fri Jan 03 16:16:22 GMT 2020 META-INF/
    69 Fri Jan 03 16:16:22 GMT 2020 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Fri Jan 03 16:11:16 GMT 2020 com/dot/something/etc/One.class
     0 Fri Jan 03 16:11:20 GMT 2020 com/dot/something/etc/Two.class
```

**You'll notice that the first path does NOT contain the prefix passed to -C, but all subsequent files do.**

Alternatively, with this list (different to list in question, as it contains the prefix):

```
$> cat list.txt
src/com/dot/something/etc/One.class
src/com/dot/something/etc/Two.class
src/com/dot/something/etc/Three.class
src/com/dot/something/etc/Four.class
```

if you re-specify the first element with the shorter path then it'll all work.

```
$> jar cvf out/myjar.jar -C src/ com/dot/something/etc/One.class   @list.txt
added manifest
adding: com/dot/something/etc/One.class(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: com/dot/something/etc/Two.class(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: com/dot/something/etc/Three.class(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: com/dot/something/etc/Four.class(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
$> jar tvf out/myjar.jar
     0 Fri Jan 03 16:17:44 GMT 2020 META-INF/
    69 Fri Jan 03 16:17:44 GMT 2020 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Fri Jan 03 16:11:16 GMT 2020 com/dot/something/etc/One.class
     0 Fri Jan 03 16:11:20 GMT 2020 com/dot/something/etc/Two.class
     0 Fri Jan 03 16:11:24 GMT 2020 com/dot/something/etc/Three.class
     0 Fri Jan 03 16:11:26 GMT 2020 com/dot/something/etc/Four.class
```

This looks like a bug to me but it's been this way for a long time, from what I can see.