# unable to acces jarfile cvf error while creating a the file

Tags: java, class, jar

When i try to create a jar file from 3 .class files
(with this command `java -jar cvf morpion.jar main.class Players.class Morpion.class`) this error appears `Error: Unable to access jarfile cvf`. i already searched some help here but everything about this error was about launching the jar file but i don't have any problem with it, it's just creating the file that is a problem.
i've tried to change cvf to cf but it just change the error message and i tried to remove the jar from `morpion.jar` in the command but nothing works.
i'm using java 18.0.1 and i have the jdk and my JAVA_HOME is set, i can find the path for the jar.exe file witheout any problem but i can't use it because "it's not an internal command or an executabable"

Comment: You are using [the `java` command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html) - but you need to use [the `jar` command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jar.html) instead. There are various related questions which may help - for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60097535/javas-jar-how-do-i-create-a-jar-file-from-a-specific-list-of-files-and-also-u).

Comment: i'm using the java command cause de jar one doesn't work (it says me ''jar' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne' which in french mean that jar isn't an internal command) when i learned how to create class files i had the same problem with javac but i just had to set JAVA_HOME but now it's set and i don't know why i can't use jar, i need another variable ?

Comment: When you installed Java, you may have also installed all these commands: `java`, `javac`, `jar` and a long list of others. You can run the `jar` command by using the full path to its location (depending on where Java was installed). For example, on Windows: `C:\path\to\java-install-location\bin\jar.exe...`. If you have an older version of Java (I think v8 or earlier) _and_ if you only installed the JRE (not the JDK) then it is possible that you do not have that command. I can't remember if `jar` was part of the old JRE distribution.

Comment: But whatever your situation, the `java` command does not _create_ JAR files. It only _uses_ them. Therefore, you can update your question to tell us what version of Java you installed (or how you are running Java), where you installed it - and whether it contains the `jar` command in its `bin` directory. Based on that, you may solve your problem for yourself (by finding the `jar` command) or we may be able to help further. Given what you say about `JAVA_HOME`, it should work - and so we do need more information to give you better help.

Comment: i just edit my first question

Comment: Thank you for the updates. Can you show us (a) the exact `jar` command you are using, and (b) what directory you are in when you run it? And (c) what is the value of `JAVA_HOME`? Also, (d) have you added the Java `bin` directory to your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: Hello back it was night in france i went sleep, so the ‘jar’ command was just jar to see the informations about this command, for the JAVA_HOME it’s on java>bin, and about the path i don’t realy understand what it is i tried a random command with it ‘path C:\Users……java\bin\jar.exe’ but it did nothing except stoping javac which was not an internal command (i just had to restart my cmd and javac worked) and for the directory when i’m running it , it’s on the file where are my .class files

Comment: OK - thank you again. You can (and should) update your question, and add the new information there, instead of using a comment. The `PATH` variable should include an entry which points to the _directory_ containing your `jar.exe` file - but don't delete any of the existing `PATH` entries - just add this new entry (if it is not already there). Apart from that, I am sorry, but I cannot see the reason why your `jar` command does not appear to run correctly, even though you can run `java` and `javac` OK. That is strange! Maybe someone else can spot the problem.